# selenium unable to locate elements

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is the part of the HTML:

```
<div style="width: 31%; float: left; text-align: left; margin-right: 2%;">
                        <label for="ctl00_MainArea_DealingAssetSelector_mnuTabs" id="ctl00_MainArea_DealingAssetSelector_Filters2_lblFilterISIN" class="above">Identifier:</label>
                        <input name="ctl00$MainArea$DealingAssetSelector$Filters2_txtFilterISIN" type="text" id="ctl00_MainArea_DealingAssetSelector_Filters2_txtFilterISIN" class="input" autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%;">
                    </div>
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User1\Python\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 857, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\User1\Python\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 435, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User1\Python\Virtualenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="ctl00_MainArea_DealingAssetSelector_Filters2_txtFilterISIN"]
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:189:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:507:5
dom.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/shared/DOM.sys.mjs:132:16
```

When i use the same code to locate other elements, it works. For example, the below works:

`elem = driver.find_element(By.ID,("RetailPageContent"))`

Can you please help in locating the first element?

The below is from the same webpage, but before login:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://platform.ardan-international.com/Auth/Login?returnUrl=%2f")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "container col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4  col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 orangeBorder") #does not work
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "row center") #does not work
driver.find_element(By.ID, "ResetPassword") #works
```

So why my quote does not locate the first two elements? If i understand this (eg if i understand how to locate the element using the class "row center"), maybe i will be able to solve my question.

Many thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Could you edit in minimal code which reproduces the issue? Here's what worked:
```py
from os import getcwd
...
with webdriver.Firefox(options=options) as driver:
  driver.get(f"file:{getcwd()}/test.html")
  driver.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_MainArea_DealingAssetSelector_Filters2_txtFilterISIN")
```
where `test.html` is the file containing your HTML code.

Comment: Thanks - i edited my question by adding some more comments at the end. It does not reproduce the actual problem, but if you can answer the last part i might be able to understand how to locate the elements that i currently cannot locate. Thanks.

Comment: Is the element inside an iFrame?

Comment: @cmarios to select multiple classes use `By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".row.center"`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. No, it looks that it is not inside an iFrame ( ctrl+u and then ctrl+f and search for iframe gives no results). The ```By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".row.center"``` works for the row center class, but still did not figure out how to locate other items such as class "container col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4  col-sm-offset-3 col-lg-3  col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 orangeBorder"